# A curious question - an algorithm to determine how a list of vectors is sorted?

Tags: algorithms

Given a list of `vectors` consisting *n* integers that has been sorted by their components in certain priority, how do you find the possible sorting keys, i.e. the order of precedence?

*Suppose there is a sorting function:*

```
def some_sort(vectors):
    priority = (vector[i],..., vector[j])
    return sorted(vectors, key=priority)
```

- where `priority` is a tuple of the same length *n* as `vector` and is some permutation of `vector` (in other words, **(*i*, ..., *j*)** is some permutation of the set **{0, ..., *n* - 1}**)

Now you are given the list `sorted_vectors` which is returned by `some_sort(vectors, key=lambda vector: (vector[i],..., vector[j]))` (it doesn't matter whether you know the original list vectors), how do you determine the permutation **(*i*, ..., *j*)**?

Comment: Not everybody knows python. Can you rephrase your question so that it doesn't require knowledge of python?

Comment: @MatchaShining Can't we have access to original list.

Comment: You can. But how does it help anyway?